# javascript closures still applies

Tags: javascript, closures

If I have a function inside another function but the inner function doesn't use the outer function's variables, will the inner function still be a closure?

```
function someFunc(){
    return function(){

         \\do some more stuff

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes it is still is a closure. Could you please give a scenario where it will be useful?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see the `function` keyword within another function, the inner function has access to variables in the outer function.

```
   function foo(x) {
      var tmp = 3;
      function bar(y) {
          alert(x + y + tmp);
      }
      bar(5);
   }
   foo(2);
```

This will always alert **10**, because `bar` can access the `x` which was defined as an argument to `foo`, and it can also access `tmp` from `foo`.

For info about closures, refer: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Comment: That is a really complicated explanation! I'm not sure the `++tmp` really helped :)

Comment: The `tmp` is in outer function, but is accessed inside inner function. This is what you wanted to know right.?